# how can i calculate total no of code line in whole project?

Tags: c, linux

see i want to count total no of code line, comment line in my whole project so is there any command or script in **linux** machine for that purpose.

Is there any script for counting no of code in particular directory?

NOTE : my code is written in c langauge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[CLOC.](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? If you see any problems with the suggested utility. please enlighten us too? or just plain dumb  downvote?

Comment: @ALS - An answer containing only a link and no explanation is not the highest quality. Or perhaps someone just doesn't like the tool?

Comment: @Bo Persson: What does one need to explain here? The Q asks for a tool the answer gives the name of the tool and the link to it. It is a popular enough tool in first place, So even if the link dies a simple google shall find the tool and If someone sees a shortcoming in the tool, why not mention it here, For us all to see it?

Comment: @Bo Persson: I wouldn't mind copy pasting the text from the tools website here just for the sake of it,Or perhaps I could even add something like You should use this nice blah blah tool but what purpose does it serve apart from wasting time?

Comment: @Als - I have never heard of the tool. :-) If you recommend it, it might be helpful to others to say *why* you recommend this.

Comment: @Bo Persson: I recommend it because it simply does what the OP asks for and not only for this particular language but a host of other languages.I do not see that reasoning as justification viable enough for a  downvote, Neither do i say One *has to* justify nor do i say *You downvoted* but Well If someone is expecting detailed answer on this the Q should have been detailed enough asking for a particular feature in detail. if not, the Q asks for a tool, the answer provides a tool which does that Period! I don't see what justification is needed as long as the answer provides what was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ wc *.c *.h
   17    41   234 file1.c
   33    83   868 header1.h
 ...
   43   189  1440 headerM.h
   10    36   300 fileN.c
 3271 11541 78807 total
```

So my directory has 3271 lines, 11541 words, and 78807 characters in files with `.c` or `.h` extensions.

`wc` should be available in any UN*X command line or downloadable and installable for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try SLOCCount: http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/

Comment: +1 I like this one. If you're using debian it is available in repositories.